# Connecting remotely to MongoDB on Windows datacenter server 2012 R2 running on Azure

Tags: mongodb, azure, windows-server-2012-r2

I tried all the things I could find:

1)  Set up a new network security group (NSG) in Azure config

2) Configured windows firewall to allow port traffic on 27017.

3) Edited the cfg file for MongoDB to bind to the outside subnet 10.0.0.4 along with the local ip.

```
net:
    bindIp: 127.0.0.1,10.0.0.4
    port: 28017
systemLog:
    destination: file
    path: c:\mongodb\logs\mongod.log
storage:
    dbPath: c:\mongodb\data\db
```

I have gone as far as disabling the windows firewall - no success.

I have gone as far as changing the network security group in the azure config to allow all traffic on all ports - no success.

[image]

I've changed MongoDB to use a non default port and updated the firewall and NSG accordingly as you can see from the cfg above - no success.

In all of the above I cannot even query the port from multiple remote machines (win 7 and win 10).

```
portqry.exe -n xxx.southcentralus.cloudapp.azure.com -e 28017 -p BOTH exits with return code 0x00000002
```

This was easy to do (configure an endpoint) on the old Virtual Machine config.  Now with these resource groups, I'm obviously missing something.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to show a snapshot of your inbound rules that you set up within the network security group?

Comment: Done.  It won't let me post the inline image, but I posted a link.

Answer (score 0):

Your NSG settings look ok. The only thing that looks suspicious is your `bindIp`. Please try setting it to:

```
net:
    bindIp: 0.0.0.0
    port: 28017
```

I recreated your configuration and this is the only difference. In fact, if I try binding to my internal ip address, `mongod` fails to start. Try binding to `0.0.0.0` - this should allow you to connect both via localhost and from the outside world.

Note: If you do want to have multiple addresses in your `bindIp`, you need to enclose the list in

`[ ... ]`

brackets.

Comment: I tried setting it to just 0.0.0.0 and restarted Mongo.  Validated in the logs that that is what it bound to.  Tried the remote connection.  No luck.  I then disabled the firewall entirely (just to eliminate it as a possibility).  No luck.  I then tried [0.0.0.0, 10.0.0.4, 127.0.0.1] and restarted Mongo.  No luck.  I had it set to 10.0.0.4 originally because that is the only interface listed when I do an ipconfig -all.  So now, the inbound rule on the NSG is wide open, windows firewall is disabled and I still can't connect remotely.  Just to be thorough,  I have this set up as a service.